# Check In Background At Certain Time

Tags: ios, nsurl

This is what I would like to do. Every day at a certain time (let's say 6:00 AM), the app would (in the background) run a script. In my case, the script is:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.exampledocument.com/example.txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```

And then send that to the user's device using a `Local Notification`. Is it possible to run that time and script in the background? I really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by send it to the users device?  You can use background fetch mode to periodically retrieve data and you can post a local notification but you cannot guarantee a particular execution time. You could use a scheduled script on an external web site and use push notification to send data to the users device. This could guarantee an execution time because it is happening on your own server but you cannot guarantee immediate receipt of the notification (device could be off or no service)

Comment: @Paulw11 I mean local notification and I would have a script to see if it is connected.

Comment: The the first scenario is the closest you can get - your cannot guarantee execution at a specific time

Comment: @Paulw11 What is the code I would use?

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/